# Html Form If statement in OnSubmit Field

Tags: javascript, php, html, if-statement, onsubmit

I'm fairly new to html/php/js and I'm running into an issue when conditionally submitting my form. Basically, what Im trying to do is have it where the confirm('Do you want to submit this form?') function only shows up if every field has a value entered (the checkform() function). If both are true, then the form will submit. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
function checkform()
{
 var myForm=document.frmhot;
 
 if(myForm.status.value==""){
  alert("Please select a timeframe status."); 
  return false;
  myForm.status.focus();
 }
    if (myForm.line.value==""){
  alert("Please select a line.");
  return false;
 }
 if(myForm.reason.value==""){
  alert("Please select a reason code.");
  return false;
 }
 if(myForm.partnum.value==""){
  alert("Please enter a part number.");
  return false;
 }
 if(myForm.badgescan.value==""){
  alert("Please enter a badge number.");
  return false;
 }
 return true;
  
} 
</script>
```

```html
<form method="post" action="newhotpartgenerate.php" name="frmhot" 
onclick="if(checkform();){
 confirm('Do you want to submit the form?');
}
>
         
<input class="button_text" type="submit"  value="Submit" name="submit" onclick= "checkform();"  />
</form>
```

Comment: Just a note, this statement `myForm.status.focus();` will never be executed because it's after a `return` statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Complete **working** solution with corrections and tweaks for IE compatibility to a certain extend.

```
<script>
    function checkform(evt)    {        
        var myForm = document.frmhot;
        var condition = true;
        if(myForm.status.value==""){
            alert("Please select a timeframe status."); 
            myForm.status.focus();
            condition = false;
        }
        if (myForm.line.value==""){
            alert("Please select a line.");
            condition = false;
        }
        if(myForm.reason.value==""){
            alert("Please select a reason code.");
            condition = false;
        }
        if(myForm.partnum.value==""){
            alert("Please enter a part number.");
            condition = false;
        }
        if(myForm.badgescan.value==""){
            alert("Please enter a badge number.");
            condition = false;
        }
        if(condition){ condition =  confirm('Do you want to submit the form?'); }

        if(!condition) {
            if(evt.preventDefault) { event.preventDefault(); }    
            else if(evt.returnValue) { evt.returnValue = false; }    
            else { return false; }
        }
    }
</script>
<form method="post" action="newhotpartgenerate.php" name="frmhot" onsubmit="checkform(event)">
    <input type="text" name="status"/>         
    <input type="text" name="line"/>
    <input type="text" name="reason"/>
    <input type="text" name="partnum"/>
    <input type="text" name="badgescan"/>
    <input class="button_text" type="submit" value="Submit"/>
 </form>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have the right idea, just extract your code into its own function and then call that in the onclick.

Add this function:

```
function checkAndConfirm() {
     if(checkform()) {
        if (confirm('Do you want to submit the form?')) {
            // submit the form
     }
}
```

And then call it from the onclick attribute:

```
<form method="post" action="newhotpartgenerate.php" name="frmhot" onclick="checkAndConfirm()">
```

Comment: That worked perfectly, thanks. However, the form still submits even if not all of the fields have values. Any ideas?

Comment: I think the issue is that you're still doing a 'post' request to newhotpartgenerate.php each time, and running the javascript on the side. You might want to instead use a simple <input type="submit"> button that will do all the validation, then if it succeeds choose to make the post request.

Comment: Just to add to Zach Sadler's answer, if you want the form to NOT submit, then you'll need to set onclick=false. So just have checkAndConfirm() return a false for the conditions you don't want to submit the form.